# SMD reflow oven baseplate material

Tags: reflow

I’m (for fun and hobby projects) making a DIY reflow oven (box, not conveyor) based on resisting heating elements and convection.

I initially used a base to hold PCB made of steel wire, but that introduces uneven thermal spread.

I have an option to make new base either using steel or aluminum plate with perforations.

My question is which material would be more suitable for this purpose?

I guess it is whether thermal conductivity of the plate should be higher or lower but I cannot find the right answer to that somehow.

Comment: Not sure if it is considered on-topic here. Or should this go to some other website?

Comment: In the title, a "backplate" would be vertical. Is it meant to say "baseplate", or perhaps "board support"? If you want an even air temperature, you could use a fan made from thin metal with the motor outside the hot part. With an even air temperature, the board could be supported on pins or a rack.

Comment: @AndrewMorton you are right, should be baseplate perhaps. I already do use fan, but wire based support introduces hot spots as I can see them on IR gun. So I think actual plate instead of wire would give more even heat distribution. But my concern is about thermal conductivity of that plate material. Whether high or lower conductivity will be better for the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sand. I have seen people use a frying pan filled with sand to for this. See this: https://hackaday.com/2019/06/05/solder-smds-with-a-pan-o-sand/

It will spread the heat evenly and touch the board evenly as well no matter what shape it is. You should be able to get very fine sand in hardware stores. It's used for mixing concrete for example.

Comment: That’s be good option if I were using a hot plate. But I am using box with a side door and board is in the middle of the door (vertically) so there is no way to put sand there.

Comment: How do all the bigger elements remain in place if the board is vertical? I think it would be a good idea to post a picture of the oven you are making.

Comment: not the board is vertical. The board is in the middle level of the door in vertical direction. Miscommunication here :D think of it as a baking oven with heating element that’s in somewhat separate chamber (and air circulation for the upper half of the main chamber).

Comment: If the heat is coming from the air, I think the material you place the board on does not matter that much as long as it's uniform and can withstand the few hundreds C°, does it?

Comment: I think it would be better if the heat was coming from the bottom through the board though instead of the top through the components...

Comment: pretty sure it does make difference which material is underneath the board as it should be a uniform thermal mass otherwise there will be hot and cold spots. So a plate instead of wire should achieve that. My question is around thermal conductivity of material as aluminum plate would heat up faster than iron one and it would affect the whole process in a different way than if it was iron but what I am not sure is which one would be a better choice.

Comment: as for the direction in which the heat comes from - I am considering boards with double sided assembly. Heat coming from the bottom would melt and displace components on the bottom before reflowing those on the top.

Comment: I am not really qualified to advice, but just thinking about it it seems to me this is straight forward - if the material is uniform - has no perforations - it conducts heat uniformly if it is heated uniformly itself, so if air moves enough it should be good for one side, but if you have 2 sides, I think the board should be held by it's sides and small components at the bottom should be held by surface tension while some heat resistant adhesive should be used for bigger ones. If you do it in passes, you should isolate the soldered side by something that has lower heat conductivity than air.